# pass parameter as webelement to make global method 'click'

Tags: typescript, webdriver, protractor

How to pass parameter as WebElement in protractor with TypeScript?
for example:

```
public click(element:element){element.click();}
```

it's doesn't work...
"[ts] Property 'click' does not exist on type 'Element'"

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `HTMLElement` so like this

```
public click(element:HTMLElement){element.click();}
```

Which does have the `click` method.